# How to implement Single Sign On in Blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, single-sign-on

I have developed one application using Blackberry 5.0 and now client want to integrate Single Sign-On Authentication Via SAML 2.0. So guide me how to implement it.

Please let me know how to implement Single sign-on in Blackberry?

Looking forward of your response.

Thanks,
Devang

Comment: I successfully implemented it using Browserfield.

Comment: I have implemented it and its working fine in Blackberry 6.0 and abvoe because it's browserfield is handling cookie while URL redirecting but in blackberry 5.0, its not working because its not handling the cookie. I have googled and found that you have to implement cookie handler. So can you please help me how to resolve(how to implement cookie handler) it in Blackberry 5.0?